# Regex need to remove unwanted characters

Tags: php, regex

Following my recent question regarding regex with HTML that has been answered here (thank you all), I made decision to stick with regex for the last time. 
My goal was to grab value **updateXXXX** from the following HTML code using cURL:

```
(...)<input type="hidden" id="_postupdate" name="_postupdate" value="updateXXXX" /><input type="hidden"(...)
```

Using

```
$regex = '/name="_postupdate" value="([^"]*)" \/><input type="hidden"/s';
if ( preg_match($regex, $page, $list) )
echo $list[0];
```

i managed to get this output:

```
name="_postupdate" value="updateXXXX" />
```

I'm sure there is a simple way to remove:

```
name="_postupdate" value="
```

and

```
" />
```

Once again, thanks for all advice and help :)

Comment: Can't you use a DOM parser?

Comment: I need this just for a small script :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `echo $list[0];` to `echo $list[1];`

You're currently outputting the whole match, when you just want the captured group `([^"]*)`.

Answer (score 1):

There should be the real result in $list[1]. Try print_r($list).